# Find user's online status

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, faye, private-pub

I am using `private_pub 1.0.3 gem` which is build on top of `faye` and able to use it in my localhost. Now I want to implement functionality to check if user online status is online or offline using this gem.

I am totally new to web sockets and found private_pub really easy to configure it so implemented it.....but Now I am stuck in the above mentioned problem. So, please let me know what is the proper solution for it.

I found this tutorial http://www.ryanepp.com/blog/how-do-i-tell-if-a-user-is-online and I think that can solve my problem....I have configured redis server and tested it through console, it is all working.....Now all I want to do is to replace `websocket-rails` part of code with our own `private_pub` gem utilization.

### UPDATE

I found these `faye` events:

```
bayeux.bind('disconnect', function(clientId) {
  // event listener logic
});

client.bind('transport:down', function() {
  // Fires when the connection is lost
});
client.bind('transport:up', function() {
  // Fires when the connection is established
});
```

But, how can I use and bind these events using `private_pub` gem

### NEW-UPDATE

I have opened issue in github for `faye-rails` and `private_pub` gem, please visite them, I have done partial solution for problem, but that didn't fully solved my problem

[private_pub issue 110](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub/issues/110)

[faye-rails issue 72](https://github.com/jamesotron/faye-rails/issues/72)

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?
In my case I've used the private pub's subscribe and unsubscribe events to hook redis up. This way i make user online on subscribe and offline on unsubscribe event.